# Testing-library: not picking up the match by text

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

No matter what I use `.getByText()`, or `.toHaveTextContent()` I am unable to select the text inside my Dom element which looks like this :

```
<h4 data-testid={playerName + "_score"}>Total Score- {score || 0}</h4>
```

Here I am trying to run the test By ID :

```
expect(screen.getByTestId("Vaibhav_score")).toHaveTextContent('Total Score- 0')
```

Not when I see the browser, I see it in two lines like :

```
Total Score-
0
```

and similary in the testing console :

```
 <div>
     <h4 data-testid="Vaibhav_score" >
                            Total Score-
                            0
     </h4>
 </div>
```

can someone help me in identifying the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because of the way the text is been rendered against the string. why no you better try with something like:

```js
expect(screen.getByTestId("Vaibhav_score")).toHaveTextContent(/^Total Score- 0/)
```

Also, retrieving by test Id is shouldn't be your first option. Maybe a better way to test it could be:

```js
expect(screen.getByText(/^Total Score-/)).toHaveTextContent(/^Total Score- 0/)
```

let me know if it helps